# Simple Winsock server doesn't work if executed in thread

Tags: c++, winsock

I want to have multiple servers in one program but if I try to put the server in a function and execute it using threads, it crashes (no compile error). Sorry for long code, but it is needed to demonstrate my issue:

```
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <thread>

#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")
#define _WINSOCK_DEPRECATED_NO_WARNINGS

int server()
{
    WSADATA data;
    WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &data);

    sockaddr_in listen_address;
    listen_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    listen_address.sin_port = htons(1000);
    listen_address.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = INADDR_ANY;


    SOCKET listen_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    bind(listen_socket, (sockaddr*)&listen_address, sizeof(listen_address));
    listen(listen_socket, SOMAXCONN);

    sockaddr client_info = { 0 };
    int socklen;
    SOCKADDR_IN addr;
    int addrlen = sizeof(addr);
    listen_socket = accept(listen_socket, (struct sockaddr*)&client_info, &addrlen);

    if (listen_socket != INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        std::cout << "New connection" << std::endl;
    }

    int iResult, iSendResult;
    char buffer[1024]{ 0 };

    do {
        iResult = recv(listen_socket, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
        if (iResult > 0) {
            std::cout << buffer << std::endl;
        }
        else if (iResult == 0)
            std::cout << "Closing connection" << std::endl;
        else {
            printf("recv failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
            closesocket(listen_socket);
            WSACleanup();
            return 1;
        }

    } while (iResult > 0);

    //clean up
    system("pause");
    closesocket(listen_socket);
    WSACleanup();
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    std::thread server_thread(server);
    return 0;
}
```

If you just run server() function it works fine but in a thread it crashed.

Comment: You never [`join`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/join) `server_thread`.

Comment: @G.M. Can I join the thread from inside of itself? for example, when the connection closes

Comment: No, a thread can't join itself.  You need to have a think about the expected lifetime of the server thread and how/when you want to shut it down.

Comment: You need to make `main()` wait until all threads have finished with their work. That is what `std::thread::join()` is meant for. If you want to run multiple threads, put them into a container, like a `std::vector`, that you can loop through calling `join()` on each thread. On a side note, `WSAStartup()`/`WSACleanup()` and `system("pause")` should be in `main()` itself, not in the threads. And you can't have multiple servers listening on the same IP/Port at the same time. And the output of `recv()` is not null-terminted, so use `std::cout.write(buffer, iResult)` instead of `std::cout << buffer`

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thank you very much. I wanted to create a server for multiple clients to connect to.

Comment: @EdwardC you don't need multiple servers for that. Just one server that calls `accept()` in a loop. You can then start a thread for each client that is accepted. Or, put the sockets into non-blocking mode and then you can multiplex `accept()`/`send()`/`recv()` into a single loop using `select()`, thus you don't need multiple threads at all. Or, you can use Overlapped I/O or I/O Completion Ports for the socket operations, and then you can use threads to handle completions of those operations. There are a lot of different ways you can approach this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The crash is because your `std::thread` is going out of scope when `main()` exits, but you are not calling `join()` or `detach()` on the thread, so the `std::thread` destructor is calling `std::terminate()` to kill your process.

Try this instead:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <cstdlib>

#define _WINSOCK_DEPRECATED_NO_WARNINGS
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")

void server()
{
    int iResult;
    char buffer[1024];

    sockaddr_in listen_address;
    listen_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    listen_address.sin_port = htons(1000);
    listen_address.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    SOCKET listen_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (listen_socket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        iResult = WSAGetLastError();
        std::cerr << "socket failed: " << iResult << "\n";
        return;
    }

    if (bind(listen_socket, (sockaddr*)&listen_address, sizeof(listen_address)) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        iResult = WSAGetLastError();
        std::cerr << "bind failed: " << iResult << "\n";
        closesocket(listen_socket);
        return;
    }

    if (listen(listen_socket, 1) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        iResult = WSAGetLastError();
        std::cerr << "listen failed: " << iResult << "\n";
        closesocket(listen_socket);
        return;
    }

    sockaddr client_info = { 0 };
    int socklen;
    int addrlen = sizeof(client_info);

    SOCKET client_socket = accept(listen_socket, (struct sockaddr*)&client_info, &addrlen);
    if (client_socket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        iResult = WSAGetLastError();
        std::cerr << "accept failed: " << iResult << "\n";
        closesocket(listen_socket);
        return;
    }

    closesocket(listen_socket);

    std::cout << "New connection" << std::endl;

    do {
        iResult = recv(client_socket, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
        if (iResult <= 0) {
            if (iResult == 0) {
                std::cout << "Closing connection" << std::endl;
            }
            else {
                iResult = WSAGetLastError();
                std::cerr << "recv failed: " << iResult << "\n";
            }
            break;
        }
        std::cout.write(buffer, iResult);
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    while (true);

    //clean up
    closesocket(client_socket);
}

int main() {
    WSADATA data;
    int iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &data);
    if (iResult != 0) {
        std::cerr << "WSAStartup failed: " << iResult << "\n";
        return 0;
    }

    std::thread server_thread(server);

    std::system("pause");
    server_thread.join();

    WSACleanup();
    return 0;
}
```

Now, having 1 client per server is not particularly useful.  To handle multiple clients with 1 server, you can call `accept()` in a loop, and then create a separate thread for each accepted client (there are better methodologies you can use for this, but below is just for demonstration purposes), eg:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <atomic>
#include <cstdlib>

#define _WINSOCK_DEPRECATED_NO_WARNINGS
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")

std::atomic<bool> stopRunning = false;

void client(SOCKET client_socket)
{
    int iResult;
    char buffer[1024];
    fd_set rfds;
    timeval timeout;

    std::cout << "New connection" << std::endl;

    while (!stopRunning.load()) {
        iResult = recv(client_socket, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
        if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            iResult = WSAGetLastError();
            if (iResult != WSAEWOULDBLOCK) {
                std::cerr << "recv failed: " << iResult << "\n";
                break;
            }

            FD_ZERO(&rfds);
            FD_SET(client_socket, &rfds);

            timeout.tv_sec = 1;
            timeout.tv_usec = 0;

            iResult = select(0, &rfds, NULL, NULL, &timeout);
            if (iResult < 0) {
                iResult = WSAGetLastError();
                std::cerr << "select failed: " << iResult << "\n";
                break;
            }

            if (iResult == 0)
                continue;
        }
        else if (iResult == 0) {
            std::cout << "Closing connection" << std::endl;
            break;
        }
        else {
            std::cout.write(buffer, iResult);
            std::cout << std::endl;
        }
    }

    //clean up
    closesocket(client_socket);
}

void server()
{
    int iResult;

    sockaddr_in listen_address;
    listen_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    listen_address.sin_port = htons(1000);
    listen_address.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    SOCKET listen_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (listen_socket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        iResult = WSAGetLastError();
        std::cerr << "socket failed: " << iResult << "\n";
        return;
    }

    u_long mode = 1;
    if (ioctlsocket(listen_socket, FIONBIO, &mode) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        iResult = WSAGetLastError();
        std::cerr << "ioctlsocket failed: " << iResult << "\n";
        closesocket(listen_socket);
        return;
    }

    if (bind(listen_socket, (sockaddr*)&listen_address, sizeof(listen_address)) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        iResult = WSAGetLastError();
        std::cerr << "bind failed: " << iResult << "\n";
        closesocket(listen_socket);
        return;
    }

    if (listen(listen_socket, SOMAXCONN) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        iResult = WSAGetLastError();
        std::cerr << "listen failed: " << iResult << "\n";
        closesocket(listen_socket);
        return;
    }

    std::vector<std::thread> clients;
    sockaddr client_info;
    int addrlen;
    SOCKET client_socket;
    fd_set rfds;
    timeval timeout;

    while (!stopRunning.load()) {
        FD_ZERO(&rfds);
        FD_SET(listen_socket, &rfds);

        timeout.tv_sec = 1;
        timeout.tv_usec = 0;

        iResult = select(0, &rfds, NULL, NULL, &timeout);
        if (iResult < 0) {
            iResult = WSAGetLastError();
            std::cerr << "select failed: " << iResult << "\n";
            break;
        }

        if (iResult > 0) {
            addrlen = sizeof(client_info);
            client_socket = accept(listen_socket, (struct sockaddr*)&client_info, &addrlen);
            if (client_socket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
                iResult = WSAGetLastError();
                std::cerr << "accept failed: " << iResult << "\n";
                break;
            }

            if (ioctlsocket(client_socket, FIONBIO, &mode) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
                iResult = WSAGetLastError();
                std::cerr << "ioctlsocket failed: " << iResult << "\n";
                closesocket(client_socket);
                continue;
            }

            threads.push_back(std::thread(client, client_socket));
        }
    }

    closesocket(listen_socket);

    stopRunning = true;
    for (auto &t : threads) {
        t.join();
    }    
}

int main() {
    WSADATA data;
    int iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &data);
    if (iResult != 0) {
        std::cerr << "WSAStartup failed: " << iResult << "\n";
        return 0;
    }

    std::thread server_thread(server);

    std::system("pause");

    stopRunning = true;
    server_thread.join();

    WSACleanup();
    return 0;
}
```

Alternatively, with all of the sockets in non-blocking mode, you don't really need to run each client in its own thread at all, eg:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <atomic>
#include <cstdlib>

#define _WINSOCK_DEPRECATED_NO_WARNINGS
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")

std::atomic<bool> stopRunning = false;

void server()
{
    int iResult;

    sockaddr_in listen_address;
    listen_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    listen_address.sin_port = htons(1000);
    listen_address.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    SOCKET listen_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (listen_socket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        iResult = WSAGetLastError();
        std::cerr << "socket failed: " << iResult << "\n";
        return;
    }

    u_long mode = 1;
    if (ioctlsocket(listen_socket, FIONBIO, &mode) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        iResult = WSAGetLastError();
        std::cerr << "ioctlsocket failed: " << iResult << "\n";
        closesocket(listen_socket);
        return;
    }

    if (bind(listen_socket, (sockaddr*)&listen_address, sizeof(listen_address)) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        iResult = WSAGetLastError();
        std::cerr << "bind failed: " << iResult << "\n";
        closesocket(listen_socket);
        return;
    }

    if (listen(listen_socket, SOMAXCONN) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        iResult = WSAGetLastError();
        std::cerr << "listen failed: " << iResult << "\n";
        closesocket(listen_socket);
        return;
    }

    std::vector<SOCKET> clients;
    SOCKET client_socket;
    sockaddr client_info;
    int addrlen;
    fd_set rfds;
    timeval timeout;
    char buffer[1024];

    while (!stopRunning.load()) {
        FD_ZERO(&rfds);
        FD_SET(listen_socket, &rfds);

        for(auto sckt : clients) {
            FD_SET(sckt, &rfds);
        }

        timeout.tv_sec = 1;
        timeout.tv_usec = 0;

        iResult = select(0, &rfds, NULL, NULL, &timeout);
        if (iResult < 0) {
            iResult = WSAGetLastError();
            std::cerr << "select failed: " << iResult << "\n";
            break;
        }

        if (iResult == 0)
            continue;

        if (FD_ISSET(listen_socket, &rfds)) {
            addrlen = sizeof(client_info);
            client_socket = accept(listen_socket, (struct sockaddr*)&client_info, &addrlen);
            if (client_socket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
                iResult = WSAGetLastError();
                std::cerr << "accept failed: " << iResult << "\n";
                break;
            }

            if (ioctlsocket(client_socket, FIONBIO, &mode) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
                iResult = WSAGetLastError();
                std::cerr << "ioctlsocket failed: " << iResult << "\n";
                closesocket(client_socket);
            }
            else {
                std::cout << "New connection" << std::endl;
                clients.push_back(client_socket);
            }
        }

        for (size_t i = 0; i < clients.size();) {
            client_socket = clients[i];

            if (FD_ISSET(client_socket, &rfds)) {
                iResult = recv(client_socket, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
                if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
                    iResult = WSAGetLastError();
                    std::cerr << "recv failed: " << iResult << "\n";
                    closesocket(client_socket);
                    clients.erase(clients.begin()+i);
                    continue;
                }

                if (iResult == 0) {
                    std::cout << "Closing connection" << std::endl;
                    closesocket(client_socket);
                    clients.erase(clients.begin()+i);
                    continue;
                }

                std::cout.write(buffer, iResult);
                std::cout << std::endl;
            }

            ++i;
        }
    }

    //clean up

    closesocket(listen_socket);

    for (auto sckt : clients) {
        closesocket(sckt);
    }
}

int main() {
    WSADATA data;
    int iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &data);
    if (iResult != 0) {
        std::cerr << "WSAStartup failed: " << iResult << "\n";
        return 0;
    }

    std::thread server_thread(server);

    std::system("pause");

    stopRunning = true;
    server_thread.join();

    WSACleanup();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is it more efficient to run each client in it's own thread ?

Comment: It really depends on how many clients you are expecting to be connected simultaneous. Using blocking socket calls in threads is easier to write code for, but not the greatest choice for performance as the number of clients increases. Using non-blocking socket calls in fewer threads may be more performant for small scale, but it is not the easiest thing to code for, either. If scalability is an issue for you, then Overlapped I/O, I/O Completion Ports, or Registered I/O are more efficient for larger scales, at the cost of more complex coding.

Comment: There are whole books on this subject.